# What's the difference between including a header and a C++ file?

Tags: c++, header, include

What's the difference between including a header(.h files) and a C++ file(.cpp files)? When I create a class, I create a .h file and .cpp file. If I want to use an object of this class should I include both of these files or not? In which cases should I include the .cpp file?

Comment: You don't include `.cpp` files, `.cpp` files include headers.

Comment: ***In which cases should I include the .cpp file?*** I say never although my convention is to not name template implementations `.cpp`. I see that some users use `.cpp` for template implementations and include that from the template header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What files are called, and what their contents is, are entirely convention. If you like to confuse people, you could call your header files `something.b` and your source files `something.r` - this will of course mean nothing useful to most people, and some people may think your files contain the language R rather than C++ sources. And your editor will probably not understand that it's C or C++ in files called `.b` - and build tools such as `Make`, `scons`, `CMake`, etc will probably not understand how to compile the your files without being "told". [Compilers also look a the filename extension to determine if it's supposed to compile as C++ or C, which of course will not work with "unconventional names"]

What is important is not what the files are called, but what they actually contain. A header (what most people call `something.h`) file should be such that it can be included anywhere, and any number of times in your project [exceptions do exist, where header files are not really meant to be included more than a single time in the entire project - for example a `version.h` which declares a string that describes the current version number].

A source file (what is conventionally called `something.cpp`, typically, should be passed to the compiler directly to be compiled, and not used as `#include "something.cpp"`. However, it is the CONTENT that determines this, not the name of the file. It's just badly named files if you use them that way.

In summary: The compiler just reads the source file passed in, then "inserts" the `#include` into the stream of code that it compiles, as if it was pasted into the original source file. The compiler doesn't really care what your file names are, where they came from, or what their content is, as long as the compiler is "ok" with the compilation as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference to include `.cpp` and `.h` files from point of view of compiler. But The content of `.cpp` and `.h` is different in common case. The `.cpp` files is for implementation of class, functions, static objects, and the `.h` files is for class definition. If you include the `.cpp` file into another `.cpp` file the content is duplicated and will fail at link stage becouse the naming collisions.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the difference between including a header(.h files) and C++ file(.cpp files)?

Supposed the `.cpp` file contains some function definitions, the latter option usually doesn't work well with commonly used build systems, and ends up with `multiple definition` errors, when the `.cpp` is included by more of one translation unit.

The exception might be having inlined all of your function definitions in the `.cpp` file.

In the very principle it's that the C/C++ preprocessor just expands the text found in either file type into the current translation unit. The file extension doesn't play any role here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. Both are handled by the preprocessor as plain text for concatenation to a single file. However, including a source might have a undesirable result (multiple definitions of variables/functions). Header files are usually protected by inclusion guards (#ifndef HEADER_H or a #pragma once) to prevent duplication of their content.

Note: The compiler does it's work after preprocessing (or invokes the preprocessor before compiling).